# Can you programatically draw pins (Markers) by distance on a Custom Google Map route

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, routes

When going to the Google website and signin in you can click on the “Maps” option from the toolbar menu at the top of the page. Click on the “My Places” button and choose “Create Map.”

There you can select to trace a route, for example, this map: https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=204898944445262337567.0004d03638beb43c93029&msa=0&ll=6.235122,-75.536343&spn=0.003088,0.004823

There's some know way that via JS (other languages are also welcome) , i could put a Pin (Marker) let say, 50 mts from the start of the route i traced? There are some distance data of the route within google, but i haven't found a good tutorial, or any answer on how doing this with these maps.

BTW, I can programatically draw a route and throw the Markers via code this way calculating the distance of the earth, but the thing is that the maps that i'm getting to start with are like the one in the link i wrote before, so the route is actually made by anyone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two Mile/Km Marker examples:

- [Km Markers every 2 km](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html)
- [Marker at 9.5km and 64.8km](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)

They use a method, GetPointAtDistance, from Mike Williams' [epoly](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm) utility, which he wrote for the v2 API and I [ported to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js)

It is possible the same can be done more natively with the v3 geometry library, but that didn't exist when I ported epoly.

You can do the same with a polyline from KML if you render it on the map as a native Google Maps API v3 Polyline using a third party library like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

Comment: i have heard that the guys from google since July 2012 don't officially support the KML, still is there though, but if there's a better way to get the info of the Polylines, that is not the KML let me know. P.S.: Why you erased the modification? I mean it was a valid way and more open if you only need certain data, or if you are not working with js, like on an android...

Comment: It wasn't just me, it was members of the community also.  You added "comments" to the answer.  That information belongs either in your question or in comments, not in the answer.