# How to get the coordinates list of a route atleast for every 10-20 metres?

Tags: google-maps

How to get coordinates of a route, atleast every 10-20 metres on the direction of the route? I'm not going to render in maps, i need it for some special purpose

Comment: Maximum distance of the route is around 20 KM

Comment: please update your code and technology

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Technology is IOT Gateway, which runs on Linux and Nodejs Application on top of it

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps API Display icon along route at a specific distance from start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152382/google-maps-api-display-icon-along-route-at-a-specific-distance-from-start)

Comment: Related question: [Add Markers Along a Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594598/add-markers-along-a-route)

Comment: Related question: [Can you programatically draw pins (Markers) by distance on a Custom Google Map route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764342/can-you-programatically-draw-pins-markers-by-distance-on-a-custom-google-map-r)

Comment: @geocodezip, thanks for the help, i was able to achieve partly, got few coordinates around 270 numbers for the stretch of 9 KM, now i'm changing the approach, I'm looking for IsLocationOnPath in nodejs technology...